# Countries with small number of sides

Tags: geography

I am looking for countries and states whose map is a polygon with a small number of sides. There are several such states in the USA, such as: Colorado (4 sides), Wyoming (4 sides), New Mexico (apparently 8 sides). But, looking at a map of the world, I could not find other countries or states that have small number of sides.

What country or state, ouside the USA, has the smallest number of sides?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not seem to be about using GIS and instead seems to be asking a trivia question related to Geography

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will be very dependent on the resolution of your data and a small country does not necessarily have a small number of sides (especially if its borders are defined by a twisty river, say). So many small countries/states will have very many more sides than some large ones. Any state/country where a border is defined by a natural feature will potentially have an almost infinite number of sides as you increase the resolution of your data and drill down into the fractal nature of the borders.

Fractals aside and back in the world of practicalities, one approach you could try would be to use your favourite GIS to select countries/states with a small (you define the limit) number of vertices.